# Get specific substring of a sequence

Tags: string, r

I've created the following matrix in R:

```
positions = cbind(seq(from = 20, to = 68, by = 4),seq(from = 22, to = 70, by = 4))
```

I also have the following string:

```
"SEQRES   1 L   36  THR PHE GLY SER GLY GLU ALA ASP CYS GLY LEU ARG PRO          "
```

I'm trying to use an apply function to make a list of substring(mystring, start.position, end.position) where the first index comes from positions[,1] and the second comes from positions[,2]. I can do this easily with a for loop but I think apply would be faster.

I can get it working as follows, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way:

```
parse.me = cbind(seq(from = 20, to = 68, by = 4),seq(from = 22, to = 70, by = 4), input)
apply(parse.me, MARGIN = 1, get.AA.seqres)

get.AA.seqres <- function(items){
start.position = as.numeric(items[1])
end.position = as.numeric(items[2])
string = items[3]
return (substr(string, start.position, end.position)  )
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just split on white space and discard the first three elements?

Comment: PDB file elements are defined by columns not by white space. Thus I'm hesitant to split on whitespace when the spec specifically mentions column numbers. Thanks for the though though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
> substring(input, positions[, 1], positions[, 2])
 [1] "THR" "PHE" "GLY" "SER" "GLY" "GLU" "ALA" "ASP" "CYS" "GLY" "LEU" "ARG" "PRO"
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Andrie's practical advice, but in case you need to go this route for some other reason, your problem sounds like it can be addressed by `Vectorize()`:

```
#Your data
positions = cbind(seq(from = 20, to = 68, by = 4),seq(from = 22, to = 70, by = 4))
input <- "SEQRES   1 L   36  THR PHE GLY SER GLY GLU ALA ASP CYS GLY LEU ARG PRO          "

#Vectorize the function substr()
vsubstr <- Vectorize(substr, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
vsubstr(input, positions[,1], positions[,2])
#-----
[1] "THR" "PHE" "GLY" "SER" "GLY" "GLU" "ALA" "ASP" "CYS" "GLY" "LEU" "ARG" "PRO"

#Or, read the help page on ?substr about the bit for recycling in the first paragraph of details

substr(rep(input, nrow(positions)), positions[,1], positions[,2])
#-----
[1] "THR" "PHE" "GLY" "SER" "GLY" "GLU" "ALA" "ASP" "CYS" "GLY" "LEU" "ARG" "PRO"
```